# Springboot, thymeleaf - auto refreshing/data loading to template

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying in Springboot mvc for some time and have a problem:
my app auto generates List of Commentaries. I'd like to show them one by one on website.

I know there is solution in js but dont know yet a lot on js. trying first in java/spring.
I found js solutions on stackoverflow but hard to me to implement them to my app - idk how/where to put js script in template nor js function in controller/service.
guys, could you guide me with the simplest solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is pretty much unintelligible. If someone could decode what it is you're asking for, I'm sure it would be too broad a question for SO.  Please read [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: When you are already using Thymeleaf you could simply add your comments to the model without using any JS.